# Node.js - Allocation failed - process out of memory even with use of JSONStream parser

Tags: memory-management, jsonstream

I'm trying to read and parse through about 12 large (ranging from 100mb+ to 500mb+) JSON files in node. I tried using JSONStream (as suggested by many others as a solution for this problem) to prevent the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

However, I'm still getting this error. This is the first time I've ever tried using a streaming file reader like this, so I'm not sure what could be the problem. Right now, the code I have is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonFileArray.length; i++) {
    if (jsonFileArray[i].match(/\.json$/)) {
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(dirPath + jsonFileArray[i]).pipe(JSONStream.parse(['records', true, 'Categories']));

      stream.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('received:', data);
        });
    }
}
```

Eventually I want to build a cumulative result object with all the parsed data from these files, but so far everything I've tried has prevented me from being able to parse through any and all of the files. Suggestions? Guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "memory-leak" branch from the JSONStream repository. This branch fixes the memory leak, however you can't use the ".." operator.

[Link to the branch](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream/tree/memory-leak)